# How do I find supremum and infimum of the set : $\{x\in\Bbb R\mid \exp(-x^2) < 1/2\}$ without using graph?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I tried this approach-
$\exp(-x^2) < 1/2$
Taking ln both sides
$$-x^2 < \ln(1/2) \iff x^2 > -\ln(1/2)$$
This implies that x is bounded below.
But according to graph this is unbounded from above and below.
How can I prove this without graph?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

First note this means $\; x^2>\ln 2\enspace (>0)$.

Next, use a basic result on inequalities:

$$\text{If }\;A\ge 0,\;\text{ then }\quad
\begin{cases}
x^2<A\iff -\sqrt A<x<\sqrt A,\\[1ex]
x^2>A\iff x<-\sqrt A\enspace\text{ or }\enspace x>\sqrt A.
\end{cases} $$

Comment: What i got from your hint is that the set can be transformed as S: (–∞,–ln2)union(ln2, ∞). Then the set will be clearly unbounded.Am I right?

Comment: It's correct. You could find a supremum or an infimum if you add some condition like $x>0$ or $x<0$, for instance.

Comment: Yes, I got it now.